# Set same height for three divs depending on the div with most content

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<style>
.homediv    {
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    background-color:white;
    padding:5px;
    overflow:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    width:32%;
    box-sizing:inherit;
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#home   {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.middle {
    margin-left:2%;
    margin-right:2%;
}
</style>

<div id="home">

<a class="homediv" href="">
<span class="hometitle">Title</span>
<p class="homedescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</a>

<a class="homediv middle" href="">
<span class="hometitle">Title</span>
<p class="homedescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</a>

<a class="homediv" href="">
<span class="hometitle">Title</span>
<p class="homedescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</a>

</div>
```

There're three columns side by side with same height but different content. That means, every div has a different height. I want all divs to have the same height as the div with the most content.

Means in this case: The middle div and the right div should expand there height to the height of the left div.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **Flexbox**

use `display: flex;` in your parent `div`.

What `display: flex;` does is that all the `children/contents` have the same height.

```
#home{
   box-sizing:border-box;
   display:flex; /* all children of equal height */
}
```

```css
.homediv    {
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    background-color:white;
    padding:5px;
    overflow:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    width:32%;
    box-sizing:inherit;
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#home   {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display : flex;
}
.middle {
    margin-left:2%;
    margin-right:2%;
}
```

```html
<div id="home">

<a class="homediv" href="">
<span class="hometitle">Title</span>
<p class="homedescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</a>

<a class="homediv middle" href="">
<span class="hometitle">Title</span>
<p class="homedescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</a>

<a class="homediv" href="">
<span class="hometitle">Title</span>
<p class="homedescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this.

```
<style>
 .homediv{ height:inherit; }
</style>

<div class="homediv">
<a href="#"></a>
</div>
<div class="homediv">
<a href="#"></a>
</div>
<div class="homediv">
<a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

The divs will have same height.

Comment: The 3 divs have the same hard coded height here. He want all to get the height of the heighter.

Comment: Height:inherit from parent class